# How can I add a border around an irregular object in php/gd?

Tags: php, image, gd

I currently have an image created with php's `imagecreatetruecolor` and modified with `imagesavealpha` and `imagecopyresampled`. The image as I currently have it is transparent around the border (with a given border width) and contains a user-submitted image.

My goal is now to draw a border around the shape of the user-submitted image. The border width and color are user-submitted, the above mentioned border of the image has the same width as the border which should be added.

In case I was a bit unclear: I don't want to just draw a rectangle but instead I want the border adapt to any possible transparent parts of the user-submitted image.

I thought about two ways to solve this problem but they seem both very inefficient to me:

- iterate over the transparent pixels and check for nearby
  non-transparent pixels or
- iterate over the non-transparent pixels and check for nearby transparent
  pixels.

Example of what I'm trying to achieve:
[Link](https://telegram.org/file/811140066/1/7fM-CwKk4F0/53f9f1fc731c63547d)
[Archived version](https://web.archive.org/web/20150821134841/https://telegram.org/file/811140066/1/7fM-CwKk4F0/53f9f1fc731c63547d)

Comment: I would use a photo editor to achieve this. It will be difficult with PHP.

Comment: Unfortunately using a photo editor would make the whole process even more tiresome. The typical workflow is uploading a zip compressed folder with 20-50 images and later downloading a zip compressed folder with the edited images.
The step of creating the border is not the first or last one in the whole process and can't be moved to the beginning or end.

Comment: I can't see any difference at all between those two images, nor understand what you are asking.

Comment: @MarkSetchell both images are the expected outcome. If your browser does not display the transparent background as white you can see the white border. The second link is just there in case the first one gets broken.